# How to prove that an infinite direct sum and product of groups is a group

Tags: group-theory

The definition I have is: given infinitely many groups $G_1,  G_2, \ldots$, the infinite direct product and sum of groups are defined by:
\begin{align*}
\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} G_i &= \{(a_1, a_2, \ldots) \mid a_i \in G_i\} \\ 
\bigoplus\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} G_i &= \{(a_1, a_2, \ldots) \mid \text{$a_i \in G_i$ and all but finitely many $a_i = e$}\}
\end{align*}

I'm trying to verify that both of these sets are groups. The first confusion I have is with the notion of a "countable tuple." I know how to define a Cartesian product for an indexed family, but is it necessary to do so in this case? Or can I treat the elements as "tuples indexed by $n$" and proceed with component-wise operations, as I would in the product, say, $G^n$.

I'll update my attempt as I better understand how to formulate these two groups.

Comment: Indeed, both inherit the group operations component-wise.

Comment: Technically for the second one 'all but finitely many $a_i=e_i$ where $e_i$ is the identity for $G_i.$

Comment: You  are not asking clarification on a step or argument from a given proof, so [proof-explanation] is not the correct tag. Take the time to readthe tagdescription and do not mis-tag.

Answer (score 1):

A "tuple" is just a function from $I=\{1,...,n\}$ to the sets from which the entries are drawn from. But in general, you could use any set as the index set. So you have a set $D$ of functions from an index set $I$ (which might be finite, countable, or uncountable) to a set of groups $G_i:i\in I$, and you define a product $f.g=h$ via $H(i) = f(i).g(i)$ for all $i\in I$. You prove this is a group operation in the normal way: for example, show that the function $e$ mapping each $i$ to the identity of $G_i$ is an identity in $D$.

Then you could show that the set $E\subseteq D$ of functions which map only finitely many $i$ to non-identity elements is a subgroup of $D$ (or show that it's a group directly).